# Liquibase context with AND

Tags: command-line, migration, database-migration, liquibase

In [liquibase documentation](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/contexts.html) is written that it is possible to define a context in a changeset specified with AND, OR, ! and parentheses. But I did not find a way to pass a `contexts=" V1.0 AND V2.0"` parameter to liquibase (via command-line) since every time I do that liquibase generates an empty SQL file. This is how I try it:

```
 .\liquibase --url=offline:mssql? `
--changeLogFile="C:\Users\Ferid\Documents\Box Sync\PRIVATE_Ferid\liquibase-3.5.5-bin\cl.xml" `
--outputFile="C:\Users\Ferid\Documents\Box Sync\PRIVATE_Ferid\liquibase-3.5.5-bin\output.sql" `
--contexts="V1.0 AND V2.0" `
updatesql
```

It works fine when I pass only one context or use `V1.0, V2.0` so that he generates all changesets with one of the two versions but I need to generate only the changesets which have both of these contexts (V1.0 AND V2.0).

Here is an example how my changelog file's context attributes look like

```
<changeSet author="Ferid" id="1536838228609-1" context="V1.0"> ... </changeSet>
<changeSet author="Ferid" id="1536838228609-2" context="V2.0"> ...</changeSet>

<changeSet author="Ferid" id="1536838228609-3" context="V1.0 AND V2.0"> ...</changeSet>
```

I have tried different syntaxes but none of them worked for me. I am using liquibase 3.5.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contexts are best used for things like environments (think DEV, STAGING, PRODUCTION). For what you are doing it is better to use labels.

Both labels and contexts can be used to control where and when changesets are applied to different environments. They are frequently used in conjunction with each other.

One key difference is expressed in this table:

```
                   labels             contexts
in commands        expression         list
in changelog       list               expression
```

So, when you are defining your changelog, each changeset can have a 'labels' attribute that can contain a comma-separated list of labels. Each changeset can have a 'contexts' attribute that can contain a complex expression of contexts. Complex expressions are things like "qa or (acme_inc and dev)"

Conversely, when using command (i.e. deploy), you can specify a complex expression for the labels, but only a list of contexts.

The article linked below goes into depth, but in general labels are useful when you can simply enumerate/describe what a changeSet is for, but the deployment time environment is complex to describe. Contexts are useful when the 'context' in which a changeset should be deployed is a complex decision that is best left to the changeset author rather than the deployer.

One place to learn more about how Liquibase handles these is in a blog post Nathan wrote: http://www.liquibase.org/2014/11/contexts-vs-labels.html

Comment: This is a good approach. Thank you very much! Maybe it would be useful to include labels (and maybe other liquibase functions I don't know) in the liquibase documentation because I did not see Nathans blog post before.